# Get duplicates in array of strings and count number of duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

What's the best way to get duplicates in an array of hashes with strings and count number of appearances.

If I have this array of hashes

```
const data = [
  {
    url: 'https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint1',
    method: 'POST'
  },
  {
    url: 'https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint2',
    method: 'POST'
  },
  {
    url: 'https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint1',
    method: 'POST'
  }
]
```

And I want to get the hashes that are duplicated and the amount of times they appear like

```
 {
    url: 'https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint1',
    method: 'POST',
    count: 2
  }, 
  {
    url: 'https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint2',
    method: 'POST',
    count: 1
  },
```

[Javascript - Counting duplicates in object array and storing the count as a new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45258566/javascript-counting-duplicates-in-object-array-and-storing-the-count-as-a-new)

Comment: What problem are you having with the answers in the link to the other question? The chosen answer in that question should be what you follow to get your answer.

Comment: if you try the answer on the question, only returns 1 line with the count of all the lines

Comment: reading through the code it actually does return an array and not a single value. I verified by copying the code and using your data and it returns exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: testes this one ? const result = [...names.reduce( (mp, o) => {
    const key = JSON.stringify([o.cat, o.sub]);
    if (!mp.has(key)) mp.set(key, { ...o, count: 0 });
    mp.get(key).count++;
    return mp;
}, new Map).values()]; and dont works

Comment: Yeah. You can change `names.reduce` to `data.reduce` and `[o.cat, o.sub]` to `[o.url, o.method]`.

Comment: o dam you are right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for that :

```js
const data = [
  {
    url: "https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint1",
    method: "POST"
  },
  {
    url: "https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint2",
    method: "POST"
  },
  {
    url: "https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint1",
    method: "POST"
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((all, curr) => {
  const ndx = all.findIndex(e => e.url === curr.url);

  if (ndx > -1) {
    all[ndx].count += 1;
  } else {
    all.push({ url: curr.url, count: 1 });
  }

  return all;
}, []);


console.log(result)
```

Comment: Almost! , is there a way to match all the keys of the hash and return all the hash info ?

Comment: @nonyck not sure i follow, can you add a sample of desired results please ?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Taki mentions, you can use the [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
const frequencies = arr =>
  Object.values(
    arr.reduce((obj, { url, method }) => {
      obj[url] = obj[url] || { url, method, count: 0 }
      obj[url].count += 1
      return obj
    }, {})
  )

const data = [
  {
    url: 'https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint1',
    method: 'POST',
  },
  {
    url: 'https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint2',
    method: 'POST',
  },
  {
    url: 'https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint1',
    method: 'POST',
  },
]

const result = frequencies(data)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using with `reduce` (or `forEach`) will simplify.

```js
const data = [
  {
    url: "https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint1",
    method: "POST"
  },
  {
    url: "https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint2",
    method: "POST"
  },
  {
    url: "https://app.mywebsite.net/endpoint1",
    method: "POST"
  }
];

const updated = data.reduce(
  (acc, curr) =>
    Object.assign(acc, {
      [curr.url]:
        curr.url in acc
          ? { ...acc[curr.url], count: acc[curr.url].count + 1 }
          : { ...curr, count: 1 }
    }),
  {}
);

console.log(updated);
```