# How to get count of duplicate objects in Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, typescript

This is an array of objects I want to get a count of the duplicate objects in the array.
What is the most concise and efficient way to find out duplicate objects?

```
[
{
  partNum: 'ACDC1007',
  brandName: 'Electric',
  supplierName: 'Electric',
},
{
  partNum: 'ACDC1007',
  brandName: 'Electric',
  supplierName: 'Electric',
},
{
  partNum: 'ACDC1007',
  brandName: 'Electric',
  supplierName: 'Electric',
},
{
  partNum: 'ACDC1009',
  brandName: 'Electric',
  supplierName: 'Electric',
},

{
  partNum: 'ACDC1000',
  brandName: 'Electric',
  supplierName: 'Electric',
}

]
```

I am looking for a way to modify the array of objects on the basis of partNum like this:

````
[
{
  partNum: 'ACDC1007',
  brandName: 'Electric',
  supplierName: 'Electric',
  count: 3
},
{
  partNum: 'ACDC1007',
  brandName: 'Electric',
  supplierName: 'Electric',
  count: 3
},
{
  partNum: 'ACDC1007',
  brandName: 'Electric',
  supplierName: 'Electric',
  count: 3
},
{
  partNum: 'ACDC1000',
  brandName: 'Electric',
  supplierName: 'Electric',
  count: 1
}
.............

] ```

Thanks
````

Comment: Do you only want to add the property `count` in the all repeated objects.

Comment: yes, I only want to add count property in each object.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried. There are many similar questions like: [Javascript - Counting duplicates in object array and storing the count as a new object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45258566) and [Get duplicates in array of strings and count number of duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60172477) and [Count duplicates within an Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10541068)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). First, count all the occurrences of all objects and then add the property dynamically.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    partNum: "ACDC1007",
    brandName: "Electric",
    supplierName: "Electric",
  },
  {
    partNum: "ACDC1007",
    brandName: "Electric",
    supplierName: "Electric",
  },
  {
    partNum: "ACDC1007",
    brandName: "Electric",
    supplierName: "Electric",
  },
  {
    partNum: "ACDC1009",
    brandName: "Electric",
    supplierName: "Electric",
  },

  {
    partNum: "ACDC1000",
    brandName: "Electric",
    supplierName: "Electric",
  },
];

const countDict = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { partNum } = curr;
  if (acc[partNum]) ++acc[partNum];
  else acc[partNum] = 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = arr.map((obj) => {
  obj["count"] = countDict[obj.partNum];
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Depends how you cange. I mean what you gonna change in this array? Elaborate please

Comment: can I achieve the same result. if I change the array to this. ?

const arr = [
{
  produsts : {
    partNum: "ACDC1007",
    brandName: "Electric",
    supplierName: "Electric",
  },
},

{
  produsts : {
    partNum: "ACDC1007",
    brandName: "Electric",
    supplierName: "Electric",
  },
},
{
  produsts : {
    partNum: "ACDC1007",
    brandName: "Electric",
    supplierName: "Electric",
  },
}
]

Comment: It won't work for nested objects. It only work for no nested objects and as long as the object contain property `partNum`

Comment: I have change the logic and it's working fine for me.

      const countDict = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {

       const { partNum } = curr.products;
        if (acc[partNum]) ++acc[partNum];
        else acc[partNum] = 1;
        return acc;
      }, {});

      const result = arr.map((obj) => {
        obj.products["isMatched"] = countDict[obj.products.partNum];
        return obj;
      });